# How to access App.Current properties in Windows Universal Apps

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp

I am trying to bind to `App.Current.XYZ` properties in my View, however this doesn't seem to be possible, here's an example of what I have:

```
sealed partial class App : Application
{
    public MyClassType MyClass { get; private set; }

    ...
```

And here is the View:

```
<Page ... 
    DataContext="{Binding MyClass, Source={x:Static Application.Current}}">
```

So, this isn't possible because `x:Static` is no longer supported in Windows Universal (or WinRT), so I have tried exposing the application property through a property in the **code-behind**, like this:

```
public MyClassType MyClass
{
    get
    {
        return Application.Current.MyClass;
    }
}
```

This doesn't work either! There is no intellisense for `MyClass`, it's completely missing. I have also tried `App.Current` and still no luck.

Any ideas why my property is not visible through `Application.Current.`? Or if there is any way I can bind to this property directly through XAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something that may work for you:

Create two classes:

```
public class MyDataProvider
{
    private static readonly MyDataContainer _myDataContainer = new MyDataContainer();

    public MyDataContainer MyDataContainer { get { return _myDataContainer; } }
}

public class MyDataContainer
{
    public MyClassType MyClass { get; private set; }

    ...
}
```

Then in App.xaml define this static resource:

```
<resources:MyDataProvider x:Key="MyDataProvider"/>
```

Now you should be able to use data binding like this in your XAML code:

```
Attribute="{Binding MyDataContainer.MyClass, Source={StaticResource MyDataProvider}}"
```

In your case you could tweak the code so that MyDataContainer is actually your app:

```
public class MyDataProvider
{
    public Application App { get { return Application.Current; } }
}
```

and write your data binding like this:

```
Attribute="{Binding App.MyClass, Source={StaticResource MyDataProvider}}"
```

In general however I would not use the App class as a provider for sources for data binding. For separation of concerns I would use something like I have above with MyDataProvider and MyDataContainer

Answer (score 4):

You need to cast Application.Current to your type like so:

```
public MyClassType MyClass
{
    get
    {
        return ((App)Application.Current).MyClass;
    }
}
```